# How to run a single test from the terminal using maven and sonarqube

Tags: java, spring, maven, sonarqube, integration-testing

I have a lot of integration test class. I want to test sonar code coverage only one test. which command I can do this from the terminal? I want to see coverage in sonarqube after runs ExampleIT test

Answer (score 0):

If you are using IntelliJ IDEA, you can use the built-in tool - https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/viewing-code-coverage-results.html.